# Changing locale language in Gentoo Linux

Tags: linux, gentoo, locale

I am trying to switch from French to English.

I did:

```
export LANG="en_EN.UTF-8"
env-update
```

I appears to work, but when I open a new SSH window it remains in French!

Comment: This is (quite obviously) not a programming question. Voting to close and move to Super User.

Comment: You are probably looking for `~/.bashrc`, or `/etc/env.d/02locale`, see docs: http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/guide-localization.xml#doc_chap2_pre1 voting for close.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you 'activated' the locale you want to use, edit `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment the following line:

`en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`.

Then, as root, you must run:

`# locale-gen`

You can now set the system locale by using eselect (which will create a file in env.d containing `LANG="en_EN.UTF-8"` and run `env-update`):

`# eselect locale set en_US.utf8`